# android reflection method invoke -- what is a receiver

Tags: java, android, reflection

I'm trying to create a custom button method by creating a class that extends AppCompatButton.  I have the process for locating the button method working 
method = actClass.getMethod(methodName, View.class); where actClass is the class for the activity invoking the button.  When I get to the code calling the method I get an exception:

```
Error = "expected receiver of type com.kana_tutor.button_demo.MainActivity,
but got java.lang.Class<com.kana_tutor.button_demo.MainActivity>"
```

I've tried using a class and an intent but neither works.  I tried just exporting the context from the MainActivity (where the method is located) and that works, but it seems like a bad idea.
What is a receiver?
Method.java describes it as "@param receiver the object on which to call this method."  Is this just a reference to the method I'm calling
I have the class the method lives in and its name.  How can I create a "receiver?"
I haven't really needed to use reflection or invoke before.
Thanks!

Comment: a) Post your code. b) You can't call an instance method without specifying an instance. That's the receiver.

Comment: I think you should also specify what you're trying to do with much more clarity-  the odds you're doing the right thing seem miniscule.  There is no need to use reflection to extend a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A receiver is actually an instance of the object which contains the method you are trying to invoke.  I say an instance because the object has to exist when you invoke it.
You probably created your method something like:

```
Method method = classInstance.getMethod(methodName, View.class);
```

and then tried to invoke it with something like

```
retValue = handler.invoke(method, view);
```

The reason that the context from MainActivity worked as your handler is it's MainActivity.this -- an instance of the MainActivity object and assuming the method you were calling was in MainActivity. the invoke would work.